# ISPConfig 3: After adding a website Apache crashing

Tags: apache, crash, ubuntu-11.10

So, I've Ubuntu 11.10 installed on my server with all components for ISPConfig 3. Everyting works fine except the Apache. When I try to add or edit an existing a website the Apache server crashes for ~20-30 seconds (after 20-30 seconds the server starts), and if I try to restart it, gives me the following error:

```
> service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.78.89.94:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.78.89.94:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.78.89.94:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.78.89.94:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Jul 25 22:31:28 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

The log file doesn't have any errors, i've followed the [Perfect Server Tutorial given on the ISPConfig page](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.04-lucid-lynx-ispconfig-3). Does somebody have an idea how to fix this?

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: This maybe suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). For what it's worth, it seems like one too many things are trying to bind to localhost:80 (0.0.0.0 and [::]). Make sure you don't have another HTTP server installed, restart the server, and then run through all the Apache configuration files by hand to make sure there isn't something causing it to try and bind twice.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The problem was with mod_ruby, because this mod was not unloaded when ISPConfig restarted the Apache server. This bug was reported already, but i didn't found it (i've spend about 5 hrs of googleing) :) If somebody has the same problem disable mod_ruby. :) Ref: http://bugtracker.ispconfig.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=2951

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged on Stack Overflow! Feel free to post an answer so it shows that you found a solution to the problem and you can help others if they run into similar issues.